# Deleting item from ListView from service caused a lot of bugs

Tags: android, listview

I have ListView of Persons, ArrayAdapter to display images of this persons. There is two buttons "like" and "dislike" under photos of each person. If I press like or dislike button, this item deleted with animation from list:

```
protected void removeListItem(View rowView, final int positon) {
    Animation out = AnimationUtils.makeOutAnimation(getActivity(), true);
    rowView.startAnimation(out);
    rowView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    Handler handle = new Handler();
    handle.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            persons.remove(positon);
            mMyAnimListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

Also there is some API that generates list of person that we can get. This API makes changes to the list (status changes to one of the next value: "none", "removed", "liked, "disliked").
If status changed to "removed" I need to remove this person from list and update ListView. I do this so:

```
if (changedPerson.getStatus().equals("removed")) {
   persons.remove(index);
   mMyAnimListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   notifyRemovedStatus(idOfChangedPerson); 
}
```

But when I do this, a lot of bugs occured:

1. List updates only after tap.
2. The fragment isn't closed if last item removed from list.
3. ArrayIdexOfBound Exception some times occured if we press on like/dislike button.

Can you help me, why is this hepenned and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was easy, here code without bugs:

```
if (changedPerson.getStatus().equals("removed")) {
   persons.remove(index);
   getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
         mMyAnimListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         if (persons.size() == 0) {
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
         }
      }});
   notifyRemovedStatus(idOfChangedPerson);
}
```

I violated this rule **"Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread"**.

This video explains working conceop:
https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud853/l-1469948762/e-1530568562/m-1530568563

And this documentation was useful: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html